# Pass Array/Object as parameter in Axios React native

Tags: react-native, post, axios

I want to pass parameter in POST request in Axios library as :

```
{
  params : 
  {
            email: email,
            password: password,
  }
}
```

I have tried :

```
axios.post(url, 
            { 
                params : {
                    email: 'a@aa.com',
                    password: 'Password!',
                    sign_in_type: '1',
                    fb_token: '',
                    google_token: ''
                }
            }, 
            {headers: headers}
        )
```

But nothing works! Please suggest if you have any idea.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
 const getData = async () => {
        const params = {
          params: {
              email: 'something@somelthing.com',
              .....
          }
        };
    try {
        const { data } = await axios({
            method: 'post', 
            url: `your url`,
            data: params,
            headers: {
             'token': token
           }
        });
     console.log(data);
    } catch(e) {
     console.log(e);
    }
 }
```

Comment: In this how i will get response? means .then method ?

Comment: in the data variable, You can use try and catch block if you want to handle errors, let me update my answer to show you more

Comment: @Samad one more thing actually i am new to this so.. do i need to do anything with getData? and data orinting in log is response?

Comment: i just have made a function named getData which you could call from somewhere